# How to set an application as default after adding it to an existing file extension?

Tags: windows, installation, registry

I have a question regarding file associations. Imagine, I have two apps: `A` and `B`. They should work with some extension `.ext`. Application A is already installed and a file with extension `.ext` was opened by program `A` at least once. After that I install an application `B`. My program adds some keys to the registry(application `A` already added it's keys)`.ext`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext]
@="B"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext\A]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext\A\ShellNew]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext\B]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext\B\ShellNew]
```

Also it adds a key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\B]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\B\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\B\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\B\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyCompany\\B\\B.exe\" \"%1\""
```

So, after the installation of my program `B` I expect files with extension `.ext` to be opened in a `B` program. But when I double click it's opened in application `A` still. And the default application for opening these files are still application `A`(i didn't choose any setting manually in explorer). How can I fix this? I want these files to be opened with my application `B` after it's installation. Both `A` and `B` are installed for all users. Thanx in advance!